# VS 2019 - CefSharp - Screen sharing options not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cefsharp

We are creating a desktop application with embedded browser that can connect to conferences at https://meet.jit.si/ We used CefSharp (v 79.1.360) that works fine with audio and camera, except that it does not open "Screen sharing" options. When that web conference is used from a regular Chrome or Firefox, a new popup is displayed with options to share entire desktop or a specific program. Please let me know if that is a settings issue in CefSharp or a limitation of all embedded browsers that they cannot provide screen sharing. Appreciate your help very much in either making this work in CefSharp or in suggesting another Browser control that works.

### Settings

```
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    // Add the --enable-media-stream flag
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capturing", "1");
    Cef.Initialize(settings);

    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://meet.jit.si/");
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(browser);

    // Allow the use of local resources in the browser
    BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
    browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
    browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
    browser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;
```

Comment: `CEF` doesn't support showing a `UI` for screen sharing, the implementation it does have is a little limited also. See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16952#p42886

Comment: See also https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1065/add-support-for-webrtc-based-screen#comment-35351034 for some more background

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, will check both links. Are you aware of any other WebBrowser control that would provide this feature ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried any of the other options in 5+ years so really couldn't say what features they support.

Comment: That is tough, thank you very much for your time